# Where is "Chrome PDF viewer" extension "mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai" located?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How can I find the folder for chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai (the hidden "Chrome PDF viewer")?

I need to access these files and change its JavaScript to send me a message before printing a PDF.

Answer (score 12):

It's an **internal component** of Chrome; it's not really a physical folder to navigate to, this is compiled into the Chrome's own files (specifically `resources.pak` - thanks, wOxxOm).

You can get the source code of that extension from the Chromium source, e.g. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/71.0.3578.98/chrome/browser/resources/pdf - note that those still need compilation with the Closure Compiler, so not usable for modification as-is.

But suppose you *do* modify and compile it. Can you install your modified version? Yes and no.

While it is technically possible to override the extension by presenting an unpacked extension with a higher `version` and the same `key` in the manifest..

[image]

..it will not actually work like that, because the manifest uses elevated "private" permissions..

```
"permissions": [
  "chrome://resources/",
  "contentSettings",
  "metricsPrivate",
  "resourcesPrivate"
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome://resources; object-src * blob: externalfile: file: filesystem: data:; plugin-types application/x-google-chrome-pdf",
```

..that can't be used from a non-internal extension:

[image]

So if you really wanted to *modify the internal PDF viewer,* you'd need to compile your own modified version of Chromium, or at the very least your own version of `resources.pak`. Probably not what you want to do.

Comment: FWIW, it's possible to rebundle the modified extension's js inside `resources.pak` which is relatively easy (grit-i18n, ChromePAK, pak_tools) compared to compiling chromium.

Comment: By all means, please edit the answer to provide info about `resources.pak`! @wOxxOm (or add your own)

Comment: See the answer and comments here: [how to unpack resources.pak from google chrome?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10633357)

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. weavatools.com (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/weava-highlighter-pdf-web/cbnaodkpfinfiipjblikofhlhlcickei?hl=en) has modified the Chrome PDF viewer and released their own plugin. When you view a pdf in chrome, weava's modified PDF viewer is used instead (chrome-extension://cbnaodkpfinfiipjblikofhlhlcickei/src/pdfviewer/web/viewer.html?file=). The whole process feels seamless. Maybe we can learn from this approach?